# BASH: How to make function work with variables instead of fixed names

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

I have this function to generate an array with the files of a folder, in shuffle order:

```
for file in /file/dir/*; do 
while i=$RANDOM; [[ ${pictures[i]} ]]; do :; done; 
pictures[i]=$file; 
done
```

But I want to make it more complex, so I can use it for many other folders/files, without the need to 'hardcode' names to the script.
So I write an external file with names, and start the script generating an array from this file.
My goal is to have arrays names, with the name same of the dir.
Something like this below, but I cannot make it work:

```
for name in "${listofnames[@]}"; do
for file in /file/"$name"/*; do 
while i=$RANDOM; [[ ${"$name"[i]} ]]; do :; done; 
"$name"[i]=$file; 
done
done
```

Comment: Is there a certain filename extension you are looking for? If so, you can look up the man pages for find and the man pages for xargs. This may make it easier to get the raw data for the array and then you could simply look up random entries

Comment: cowboy, using LS and or FIND to build arrays is a big no in bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution, assuming that:

- you have bash version 4.0 or better;
- you have the `shuf` command installed; and
- your filenames do not have newline characters

```
mapfile -t "$name" < <(ls -d "/file/$name/*" | shuf)
```

(Of course, you need to wrap that in the for loop over the list of names.)

`mapfile` (which is a bash-4.0+ feature) reads it's standard input one line at a time into the array named by its positional argument. The `-t` option causes the trailing newline character to be trimmed from each line.

`shuf` (in GNU coreutils) shuffles its input.

The first two requirements may not be true on a MacOSX installation. Here's a slightly more general alternative (which still requires `shuf`), and uses a temporary array. In this one, you *must* make sure that `$name` is a valid name; otherwise, you're opening a security hole with the `eval`. The test I put in is not quite good enough; it should also check that the first character of `$name` is a letter (and therefore that it has a first character).

```
if [[ $name == *[^a-zA-Z0-9_]* ]]; then
  echo "'$name' is not a valid array name" >> /dev/stderr
else
  unset $name
  declare -a $name
  files_=(file/$name/*)
  eval "$(printf "$name"'+=("${files_[%s-1]}")\n' \
                 $(shuf -i 1-${#files_[@]}))"
  unset files_
fi
```

**Edit: slight simplification:**

```
if [[ $name == *[^a-zA-Z0-9_]* ]]; then
  echo "'$name' is not a valid array name" >> /dev/stderr
else
  unset $name
  files_=(/file/$name/*)
  eval "$name=($(printf '"${files_[%s-1]}" ' $(shuf -i 1-${#files_[@]})))"
  unset files_
fi
```

With bash 4.3, this can be simplified further by using [namerefs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters). Namerefs are intended precisely for the case where one wishes to pass the name of an array as an argument to a shell function. Here's a function which assigns a shuffled list of filenames (from the path specified as the second argument) to an array (specified as the first argument).

```
# Requires bash v4.3 or better
shuffile() {
  local name_="$1" path_="${2:-.}"
  if [[ $name_ == *[^a-zA-Z0-9_]* ]]; then
    echo "'$name_' is not a valid array name" >> /dev/stderr
    return 1
  fi
  unset $name_
  declare -ag $name_
  declare -n array_=$name_
  files_=($path_/*)
  for index_ in $(shuf -i 1-${#files_[@]}); do
    array_+=("${files_[index_]}")
  done
}
```

Comment: The first example, with LS, worked, but parsing ls is not good pratice. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.  The second example seems a very good aproach, but in my case I only get arrays with 1 string, trying to understand it more. I am using bash 4.2.

Comment: @fredfs: I'm aware of that faq entry and I added the condition under which it won't work: filenames which include newlines. Those are pretty rare, but if you think it is possible in your case, you need a different solution. Sorry about the typo in the second solution; I think it's fixed now.

Comment: @fredfs: I also added a solution using namerefs, but they are a bash 4.3 feature so you won't be able to use it until you upgrade.